# Debugger for debugging my OS

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, error-handling, operating-system

I want a debugger to debug my OS. At many places i am not being able to figure out what is wrong. **So is there any debugger which can debug operating systems**? can i do it with gdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a solution which emulates another computer on your computer - essentially, a virtual machine. The most obvious ones which come to mind instantly are VirtualBox and VMware, but those weren't designed with debugging the machine and/or the OS.

What you're looking for is either [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) or [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page). Both (as far as I remember) can be integrated with gdb in order to set breakpoints and analyze the execution of your code. You might also want to read [this OSdev.org article](http://wiki.osdev.org/How_Do_I_Use_A_Debugger_With_My_OS).

Answer (score 3):

I primarily use [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) for testing my OS projects. It includes a helpful debugger (bochsdbg).